# Directx 11 2D ortho

Tags: c++, directx-11

I startet with Directx 11 and I have some problems with setting up the camera.
I want to set the origin to the top-left of the sceen, currently it is on bot-left this is how I set it up:

```
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&mProjection);
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&mView);

mPosition = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f };
mTarget = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
mUp = D3DXVECTOR3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&mProjection,
    0.0f, static_cast<Float32>(WindowWidth),
    0.0f, static_cast<Float32>(WindowHeight), 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

and here is how I want it [image]

this is currently my coord system: [image]

Comment: You should avoid using the legacy D3DXMath library. It's only supported in the deprecated ``D3DX11`` helper library. See [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swap y parameters for building the matrix:

```
D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&mProjection,
0.0f, static_cast<Float32>(WindowWidth),
static_cast<Float32>(WindowHeight), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: sry it didnt work if I do this I don't see the texture anymore

Comment: can u give me vertices? also, check that ur triangles aren't now back culled

Comment: OMG I FORGOT TO CHANGE THE VERTICES omg thank you very much you are the best